# Issue with passwords on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, password

I've recently switched from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) and I'm having an issue regarding passwords in Chrome. In windows, if I wanted to see my saved passwords, I would go to the chrome://settings/passwords section of chrome, press on the eye icon, windows would ask me to fill in my device password, and only after that, I was able to see my saved passwords in chrome.

But on Linux chrome does not ask me for my device password once I click on the eye icon in the password manager, and the passwords are visible after just one click. I don't want everybody, having access to my pc and chrome browser, to be able to see my passwords with just one click. I understand that bypassing windows password is really simple but it's still better than no protection at all.

Is there a way to password protect my saved passwords in chrome on Linux?